# EventBus - @Subscribe annotated method is never used

Tags: java, android, android-studio, greenrobot-eventbus

When using the [greenrobot EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/) library, all `@Subscribe`-annotated methods are displayed in light grey with a warning **Method onMyEvent() is never used** in Android Studio.

Is there a way to automatically suppress this warning (as the method is not directly called from code, but in response to an event on the event bus)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can turn it off by pointing to left of the light greyed code.

Then after bulb icon appear, click and select 'Suppress method annotated by org.greenrobot...'

---

#### UPDATE

Found new working plugin for EventBus 3 IntelliJ at
[eventbus3-intellij-plugin](https://github.com/likfe/eventbus3-intellij-plugin). This is a working fork of [Shinnosuke Kugimiya eventbus3-intellij-plugin](https://github.com/kgmyshin/eventbus3-intellij-plugin).

Working with Android Studio 2.1.3.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Is there a way to make this the default for a fresh clone via the build system or other config file, **without** committing IDE files (.idea/) to source control?

Comment: I don't know if there is another ways. But recently I found that there is a plugin for @Subscribe EventBus at [Intellij Plugin for nagivation](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/issues/84). Haven't try. If you've try it, please inform me..:D

Comment: @friederbluemle: Found a working plugin for EventBus!. Please read my updated answer ;)

Comment: Hi , how u fixed this issue ?